# How can I quickly test for the presence of an Xserver

Tags: xserver, display

I have a setup such that sometimes I use xterm and sometimes I use putty. The command

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

takes longer to run when I am on putty because there is no xserver at DISPLAY.

Without getting into a heated discussion of whether or not my setup is right (because I can't change it), or whether the time difference is significant (no, it's not, but if you don't ask, you'll never learn), is there a way to ping the supposed xserver at DISPLAY to that it comes back instantaneously if there is no xserver there? That way I could set a flag and skip further X client calls, instead of calling xmodmap (or xterm or any other X client) and waiting for the inevitable timeout and 'unable to open display at' message.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmodmap 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
if (($?))
then
    ## There is no xserver. Do not set any of this up.
    return 0 ## return, not exit because this script is meant to be 'dotted in'
fi
```